# What's the method of bolding Excel subtotals from Access vba?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an Access 2010 application where I run a SQL query and output the results to Excel.  I'm using the Excel subtotal command to create subtotals.  That works fine, but on the total rows only the text ("XXX Count") is bold and the values are not bold.  Our client would like the entire row bold.  I've tried a couple ways without success.  How do I do the entire row in the subtotals?

So here is what I currently have:

[image]

This is correct except I need all of row 5, 8, 16, and 17 bold like this:

[image]

Here is my code to create the Excel file from Access (this all works except for the bold issues):

```
    Public Sub ExportToExcel(query)

    Dim appXL As Object
    Dim wbk As Object
    Dim wksNew As Object

    Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wbk = appXL.Workbooks.Add
    Set wksNew = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appXL.Visible = True
    Set wbk = appXL.Workbooks.Add
    Set wksNew = wbk.Worksheets(1)

    Set cn = CurrentProject.AccessConnection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
      Set .ActiveConnection = cn
      .Source = query
      .Open
    End With

    With rs
        'Put recordset into new wks
        wksNew.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

        'And add headers
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
          wksNew.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = .Fields(i).Name
          wksNew.Cells(1, i + 1).Font.Bold = True
          wksNew.Cells(1, i + 1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Next i

        'Now, while the recordset is available...
        'The recordset has .fields.count fields
        'Subtotals are wanted from field 7 to the end
        If .Fields.Count > 13 Then
            ReDim ary(14 To .Fields.Count - 1)
            For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
                ary(i) = i
            Next i

            wksNew.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.SubTotal GroupBy:=1, _
                TotalList:=ary, Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True

        End If

        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

I tried this code based on [this website](http://excel.tips.net/T002984_Formatting_Subtotal_Rows.html):

```
Dim rCell As Range
    wksNew.Columns("A:A").Select

Dim rCell As Range

For Each rCell In Selection
    If Right(rCell.Value, 5) = "Count" Then
        Rows(rCell.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
    End If
Next
```

but it returned a "Method or data member not found" error on the item rCell.Value.

I also tried it like this:

```
            Dim rCell As Range
        wksNew.Columns("A:A").Select

        For Each rCell In Selection
            If Right(rCell, 5) = "Count" Then
                Selection.Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next
```

But I got the error "ActiveX component can't create object" on the For Each line.

How do I bold the entire row for the subtotals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions.  No one posted a solution that worked entirely, so here's what I ended up using:

```
    Dim c As Object
    For Each c In wksNew.Range("A1:A500")
        If c.Value Like "*Total" Then
            c.Offset(0, 13).Font.Bold = True
            c.Offset(0, 14).Font.Bold = True
            c.Offset(0, 15).Font.Bold = True
       End If
    Next
```

The only thing that concerns me is that I'm assuming this only has 500 rows.  I couldn't find a way to find the number of rows and have it search only those.  If I included the whole column, it took a couple minutes to complete the loop which I didn't think the client would like.  Any suggestions on how to find the last row?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because Access doesn't know what `Selection` is unless you tell it that it's connected to your Excel instance.

```
For Each rCell In Selection
```

However, don't need to select anything, or check the whole column:

```
    Dim rCell As Range

    For Each rCell In wksNew.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
        If Right(rCell, 5) = "Count" Then
            rCell.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I get a "type mismatch" error on the for each line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a Pivot Table?? It is easier to manage format or layout and you don't have to change too much your code because you just put your `RecordSet` in a `PivotTableCache` like the [second example in this.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839885.aspx)

Comment: I've already got the subtotal working, so I'd hate to redo it.  And that just brings me to the problem of how to format in a pivot table.  I consider this a last resort though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping, I'd suggest collapsing the outline and formatting the visible cells:

```
with wksNew.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    .Outlinelevel = 2
    .specialcells(12).Font.Bold = True
    .Outlinelevel = 3
End With
```

Comment: Got the message "unable to set the OutlineLevel property of the Range class" on the line Outlinelevel = 2.  I do like the idea of not looping through each row.  Let me know if you have an idea how to fix this.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I would

1. Display level 2 of the outline, all the subtotals
2. Select the whole area
3. Use GoTo Special to select only visible cells
4. Apply the formatting
5. Change the header row formatting if it should be different
6. Display all the levels again (level 3)

This code demonstrates:

```
Sub Macro4()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Font.Bold = True
    'change the header row if necessary
    Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Font.Italic = True
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=3
End Sub
```

Comment: Got a message saying "Method or data member not found" on the ScreenUpdating line.  If I leave out that line, it runs without errors, but doesn't change anything.  The sub total headers in column A are still bold, but the subtotal values in the other cells is not bold.

Comment: The Excel Application object in your code is `appXL`. You need to adapt the code for your circumstances not just copy and paste it. In particular, you probably need to be specific in the worksheets you reference.